# JDBC Authentication Using a Hashed Password (Oracle 11.2.0.4)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, password-hash

I am trying to implement Hashed passwords in my web application using SCrypt (Spring Security). Since I am new to all this, needless to say, I didn't think it all through.

My application was using encrypted passwords using Jasypt which it used to decrypt and send it across to do the JDBC authentication.

Now that I am doing hashes, there is no way to know the real password. Is there a way to get the authentication done with hased passwords, or do I have to leave the encryption thing in just for the JDBC part?

If there is a way, please do let me know how to do it?

Comment: Oracle will require the actual password to perform authentication. It has no way to match a hash generated by a 3rd party with the hashes it stores internally.

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for the input!